# Police Officers Knocking at your door

Tags: united-states, human-rights, illinois, civil

When a police officer is knocking at your door, do they have to tell you or introduce themselves as police officers??

Comment: In what country?

Comment: Sorry, in the state of Illinois

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what the officer wants to do. If the officer is under cover, s/he may choose not to identify as a police officer. If the desire is to search the house, or to arrest someone, the officer(s) do need to identify themselves. If the desire is just to talk to/question a possible witness, officers normally do identify themselves, but I am not sure that this is legally required.

Comment: It was just for questioning, my daughter stated they were pounding on the door, didn't state who they were, she wasn't going to answer it, but i was on the phone with her, I told her to go ahead, it was 2 police officers asking about the accident that she had, had. No tickets were given, just questions.

Comment: @RitaR. Your daughter would have been wise to call the police station and verify that there were two officers dispatched to her address.